# Remove leading 3 zeros in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Unsure if this is the right platform to ask this...

I want to remove the leading 3 zeros from a column in Excel.

The numbers in the column look like this:

```
000123456-001
000023568-001
000568975-001
000000235-001
```

I was able to format the column into text, but that's where I'm stuck.  I don't see any way to format the cells to remove the first 3 zeros.

How do I remove the leading 3 zeros?

Comment: you cannot format text, so unless the cells are number formatted `000000000-000` you will need to use MID in another column:  `=MID(A1,4,10)`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I will convert it back from text and then add the formula.  Testing...

Comment: @ScottCraner - That appears to have worked, but for some reason, it's removing the final 1 at the end.  Thoughts?

Comment: @ScottCraner - Never mind.  I fixed it.  I used the following:  =MID(A1,4,11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)

Would that work for you?

Comment: That appears to have worked as well.  ScottCraner suggested using =MID and that worked.  I guess there are multiple ways to solve it.